# Pick odd one out from "man, drone, bison, bull"

Tags: word-choice, analogy, reasoning

> Part 1

Pick out the word in each of the following that is different (Odd One Out)

Man, drone, bison, bull

The answer is - bison.

PS - I just want to know the reason or the logic used here to pick 'bison' the odd one out.

Meanings:

1. Man : a human being of either sex; a person.
2. drone : a continuous low humming sound; a continuous musical note of low pitch.
3. bison : a humpbacked shaggy-haired wild ox native to North America and Europe.
4. bull : an uncastrated male bovine animal; push or move powerfully or violently.

Comment: What a bizarre question. There are several ways you could analyze this set. I suspect they probably mean that 1, 2, and 4 are male (a drone is a [male bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(bee))) whereas 3 describes both sexes. (Despite the definition you quoted, "man" usually means "male" nowadays.) But another breakdown would be that 2, 3, and 4 are all animals where as 1 is human. Or even 1, 3, and 4 are all mammals whereas 2 is an insect. Or bison is the only one not to be found outside North America and Europe. ;)

Comment: P.S. Welcome! We hope you'll take the **[tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)** and visit the **[Help Centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help)**, and of course ask more questions!

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thank you for the help. Can you help with the part 2 as well. I just edited it. :)

Comment: "Initiative" is the only noun. (The definitions aren't the most helpful, because they make it sound like 3 and 4 are also nouns. They're adjectives.)

Comment: You should ask the second part as a new question.

Comment: Please move Part 2 to a separate question. This helps us write answers that are shorter, easier to understand, and easier to find in searches.

Comment: Before seeing the details, I thought it was "drone" because I tihnk of a drone is a remote controlled machine, while man, bison and bull are all living things. So this question is potentially ambiguous. However, if it was written before 2005 or so, the writer would have no way of knowing that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some other senses of the words than the ones you found are most relevant. Here's what stands out most clearly to me (native AmE):

1. man: an adult **male** human.
2. drone: a **male** ant, bee, or wasp.
3. bison: a buffalo.
4. bull: a **male** cow.

So, **bison** stands out as the only one that doesn't mean the male of the species.

The word **man** *also* means a human of either sex. English has a number of words like this, where one sense of the word fully encompasses another sense. For example, humans are distinguished from **animals**, but also humans are a species of **animal**. A **drink** is a serving of any beverage, but a **drink** is also specifically an alcoholic beverage. When people say **rectangle**, they usually mean a shape different from a square, but in another sense, a square is a **rectangle** with all four sides equal. Somehow, these ambiguities seldom cause confusion.

One reason this question is pretty easy is because even though **man** has a generic sense that includes both sexes, it's a *secondary sense* of the word, in addition to being fairly rare today due to attempts to remove sexism from English. The primary sense has always been "adult male human".

By the way, usually the word for the male of a species also serves as the generic term for both sexes of that species: for example, [**lion**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lion#English), [**peacock**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peacock#English), [**boar**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boar#English). The only exception I've ever heard of is [**cow**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cow#English): *cow* primarily means the adult female of that species, just as *man* primarily means the adult male of our species, but *cow* is also a generic term for any animal of that species regardless of its sex or age. This might be one reason why **bull** drew me into noticing the male senses of the other words. Also, **bull** is the name specifically for the male of many species; [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names) is a big list.

## A note about salience

By the way, this would be a terrible exam question, because other answers are also reasonable. For example, **man** is the only human; the others are animals (non-human animals, that is). [Luke Sawczak's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133061/pick-odd-one-out-from-man-drone-bison-bull/133068#comment268204_133061) provides other reasonable interpretations, and [Peter's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/133065/6700) gives two more. My explanation above tells how the maleness of three of the senses became most salient in the mind of one native speaker.

Awareness of what is most [salient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salience_(language)) about words is crucial for communicating, since that's what guides your listener's attention to what you want them to see or think of. My main point here is that maleness is extremely salient in the words **man**  and **bull**—the latter especially just after being [primed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) by the word **bison** to think of animals. That tends to *make* the male sense of **drone** more salient, when normally it wouldn't be. This won't work the same way for all fluent speakers, but I'm sure it's very common. Many native speakers, especially if looking at this question casually or quickly, might not even notice that other answers are also just as reasonable.

Comment: Without context there can be no salience.

Answer (score 5):

In your first question

> bison

may be the correct answer because it is the only *two syllable* word in the group.

**Bison is also the only word that is the *plural* form.**

In your second question

> intuitive
>   talkative
>   quantitative

are all behavioral characteristics or *adjectives*

> initiative

is not.

Should this be posted in [puzzling.stackexchange.com](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: I think it's fine to ask it here as long as the OP is hoping for an answer aimed primarily at giving help with learning English.

Comment: Are people downvoting this answer because they're thinking that "two syllables" is wrong? It distinguishes just as unambiguously as the explanation I and user184411 gave: indeed, all the other words have in common that they are one syllable.

Comment: @BenK - I agree that it’s worth mentioning in the discussion, but most exam questions wouldn’t have that be the differentiation, so it’s unlikely to be the reason or the answer. (Not my downvote; just venturing a guess.)

Comment: @J.R. OP has not actually given the context of the question e.g. whether it is from an **exam**.

Comment: @Peter - Yeah, most Mensa questions wouldn’t use syllables as the differentiator, either.

Comment: Editted answer for all you nonsyllabic counters...

Comment: For those who are searching for the question. Part 2 - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133198/pick-out-the-word-in-each-of-the-following-that-is-different-odd-one-out

Comment: "Plural" is quite good. It's plausible that the person who wrote the question intended that distinction.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been mentioned in a comment, and it is the correct answer.  Another meaning of "drone" is a male bee.

"Bison" is a species; a bison can be male or female.  The other words identifies males of different species.