# Pick out the word in each of the following that is different (Odd One Out)

Tags: reasoning, analogy, verbal-noun

Pick out the word in each of the following that is different (Odd One Out)

Intuitive, initiative, talkative, quantitative

The answer is - initiative.

PS - I just want to know the reason or the logic used here to pick 'initiative' the odd one out.

Meanings:

Intuitive : when one feels something to be true without conscious reasoning.
Initiative : ability to initiate and assess things, to take charge before others do.
Talkative : one who talks a lot.
quantitative : ample quantity

Comment: I thought at first this was a trivial question, since it's easy to look the words up and establish that they're all adjectives except the noun ***initiative***. But on reflection I can see there's a genuine issue regarding the ***-ive*** suffix. Most people would classify ***sensitive*** as an adjective *(responsive to or aware of feelings)*, but presented with *She is a sensitive*, they'll immediately interpret it as a ***noun*** with the highly specific sense *a person who is believed to respond to paranormal influences*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Note that thinking "maybe the difference is the part of speech" is itself not trivial to think of. It's fairly obvious to a fluent speaker, of course, but not to someone who isn't accustomed to these words on the basis of a lot of usage. Comparing the parts of speech wouldn't work on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/133061/6700), and indeed a fluent speaker probably wouldn't even think to try it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Initiative" is the only noun. (The definitions aren't the most helpful, because they make it sound like 3 and 4 are also nouns. They're adjectives.)

as answered by @LukeSawczak

Comment: What dictionary did you consult? A good dictionary will usually tell you what part of speech the word is. All the words you listed are adjectives, but *initiative* can **also** be a noun. Look it up [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initiative), for example, and notice the *n.* before the definition – it stands for *noun*; the *adj.* stands for *adjective*.

Comment: "[Intuitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intuitive#Noun)" is also a noun. (I think @userr2684291 meant to say that "[initiative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initiative#Adjective)" is also an adjective, which is true.) But I'm pretty sure this answer is right. In their most _typical_ usages, only "initiative" is a noun, and the others are adjectives.

Comment: @BenKovitz Oh, I didn't know that; thanks – not even the OED (second edition) registers that sense of the word. I would think that *intuitive* as a noun is some kind of specialistic use which you could do with *talkative* as well. For example, I might be talking about *a talkative* in my *social intelligence* book as a type of person which I'm trying to contrast with *a non-talkative* or some such. The same with *quantitative* in some scientific book with deals with measurements, etc.